# SQL - How to take data from one table, and insert it into another

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to go through my users table, and if the rank column is a certain value, then I want to insert a row into the messages table, with one column, "to", being the username column from the users table, and the rest of the columns in the inserted row need to be a predefined value. I'm having trouble making this work- any help?

MySQL Configuration: (Those which are needed)

Users table:

```
id|username|rank
```

Messages table:

```
id|to|from|body|subject
```

(`to` needs to be from the `users` table, `from`,`body`,and `subject` need to be a predefined string

I tried to figure something out like this, but it's not just quite all I need it to do. I got this code and modified it from another Stack Overflow question that was similar to this one.

```
INSERT INTO `messages` (`from`,`to`,`subject`,`body`)  
SELECT `id`,`rank`
  FROM `users`
 WHERE `rank`='Super'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string literals enclosed in single quotes as column values.  It is safe to intermix them with the actual column values from the rows returned by the `SELECT` portion of your `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO `messages` (`from`, `to`, `subject`, `body)
  SELECT 
   /* single-quote string literals to use them in the INSERT INTO...SELECT */
   'Predefined string From',
   /* Intermixed with column values from the rows returned by the SELECT */
   `username`,
   'Predefined string subject',
   'Predefined string body'
  FROM `users`
  WHERE `rank`='Super'
```